# There is only s̶i̶x̶t̶y one place he can be

Tags: chess

*This puzzle is not mine, although I don't have any reference as to where it originated from. I discovered it when I was a student, some fifteen years ago. It has been among my favourite chess puzzles since then. Could be very well known or a duplicate, but I couldn't find it in the database.*

The following position is legal, except that the White King (and the White King only) is not displayed. Find it.

[image]

Comment: It appears this problem may have originated from *The Chess Mysteries of the Arabian Knights* by Raymond Smullyan.

Comment: Related on Chess.SE: [How does one know if a position is not reachable from a series of legal moves from the starting position?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/23538/7792), showing some examples of this kind of puzzle (retrograde analysis), including this particular one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The white king must be on square

> c3

Explanation:

> First, we determine which side is to move. Unless the white king blocks the a4-d1 diagonal, the black king is in check. The king can't be on c2 since it would attack the black king; on b3, White would be to move but there's no way this double-check could have happened in a real game; there's no way to clear both the b3-d5 diagonal and the b3-b5 file with one move from the black rook or the black bishop. Black simply couldn't have played Bb4-d5 or Rc4-b5. So the black king is in check and White made the last move.

So, what was the last move?

> The bishop can't have moved along the d1-a4 diagonal, because it would give check on c2 and d3 as well. So it must be a *discovered* check, caused by a move from the white king, from b3 to another square.

But ...

> doesn't this lead to the same problem as before? On b3, the White king is still in double check. No, because there *is* a move which simultaneously clears the b3-d5 diagonal and the b3-b5 file, but it requires extra pieces: an en-passant capture from b4 to c3, capturing a pawn on c4. Since we have an extra (half-)move compared to the situation above, we can use that move to get rid of the black pawn.

So,

> if White played 1. c2-c4, Black can play 1... b4xc3 e.p., White responds with 2. Kxc3 and we're in the diagram in the question with the White king on c3.

Comment: ... but it doesn't include an explanation why this is the only possible solution (which took me a while to write down...)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Glorfindel's answer eliminates other possibilities.

Answer (score 14):

> The last move in this position was Bd5+. White blocked the check with c4, black gave double check by capturing en passant bxc, and the king took the pawn on c3.
>  [image: chessboard]

Comment: Um... to me, it looks like rot13(gur cnja vf ba p2)... :P

Comment: I've ROT13-ed part of the comment so that it doesn't appear as an immediate spoiler. Check the image you've posted.

Comment: That was super quick. Did you know the problem before? Do you know where it is from?

Comment: Your answer says that "rot13(gur xvat gbbx gur cnja ba p3)", however that square looks empty, unless there's actually more behind the image.

Comment: @EKons After the black pawn captures en passant, it is on c3 for the white king to capture.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier It's possible that I've seen it before, but I just logically concluded en passant was necessary for a double check.

Comment: I got another generation path for the same position w/o any pawns.

Comment: ...RN4+, KB3+. The rook could have been on QR4 or QB4. White king was on QN4 or QN2.

Comment: Ah oops. My bad.